# How to Resolved multiple Services. Swift NetService NetServiceBrowser

Tags: swift

I have 2 machines running the same service. If I start the service on machine 1 then wait 1 second and start service on machine 2 both services will be resolved. However, if both services start the same time and the Xcode project is run only one machine shows resolved addresses

```
    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind svc: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
        // Resolve the service in 5 seconds
        service = svc
        service?.delegate = self
        service?.resolve(withTimeout: 5)
        NSLog("service found")
```